# DAX-Data Model Calculated Measure Blank Result in Excel 2016

Tags: dax

`DAX-After Data` been loaded to the data model and I call calculated the 
`TotalSale:=([Revenue]) Column` which works fine just for me to use the previous measure to calculate the LY

```
Sale:=Calculate([TotalSale]),Sameperiodlastyear('Calender'([Date]))
```

The result showing blank. Please help how to go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. Are these measures or columns that you calculated? A screenshot / preview of your data model would help.

Comment: Do you have time as a part of your report? I think the LY measure needs that to be able to work.